# Examples of some Pointwise Convergent Sequences of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I have recently come across pointwise/uniformly convergent sequences of functions, and I am hoping if someone could give some examples of certain sequences of functions so that I could understand the concept better. Thanks!

> • Pointwise convergent sequences that do / do not preserve continuity,
>
> • Pointwise convergent sequences that do / do not preserve
> integrals.

It seems that $f_n(x) = x^n$ is an example that do not preserve continuity?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Your question is not clear: a sequence of complex numbers is *always* pointwise converging and uniform convergence has not any meaning for such an object. Are you asking about **sequences of functions**? If so, please edit your question and take a little care of it.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thanks, I have made it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two useful (non)examples and one somewhat trivial well-behaved example.

**Example 1.** Take $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^n}$ for $x\in [0,1]$. By a direct calculation, we see
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\in [0,1)\\
\frac{1}{2}&x=1.
\end{cases}$$
Here, the pointwise limit has a discontinuity. You should try to prove why this is not a uniformly convergent family.

**Example 2.** Define the characteristic function
$$ \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\in [0,1/n]\\
0& x\not\in [0,1/n].
\end{cases}$$
Next. set $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$. Then for any $n$, we have 
$$ \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=1.$$
However, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)\equiv 0.$ In particular, we do *not* have uniform convergence. As a consequence, we can see that 
$$ \int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)dx=\int_0^10\cdot dx=0.$$
So, the limit does not preserve the integral in this case.

**Example 3.** An easy example of uniform convergence is something like $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{n+1} x$ on $[0,1]$ which is continuous. Clearly, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)= f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$. Furthermore, 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{n}{n+1}x dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1 xdx=\int_0^1f(x)dx.$$

Comment: I'm wondering about your second example. I'm struggling to see how $f(x)=0$ when $n\to \infty$. If $x\neq 0$, then yes $f(x)=0$. But If $x=0,$ then $f(x)$ is infinity, right?